# Can anyone explain use of javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater in this code

Tags: java, swing, interface

I found this code strange. Because there is another function in before the parenthesis closed. Can you explain how it works?

```
javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {     
    public void run() {
        createAndShowGUI(); 
    }
});
```

------ The full code is below. This code is not belong to me. I found it while I am googling.

```
package pkginterface;

import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Interface extends JFrame implements ActionListener {    

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Interface() {
        // set flow layout for the frame
        this.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        JButton button = new JButton("Java Code Geeks - Java Examples");
        //add Button
        add(button);
        //set action listeners for buttons
        button.addActionListener(this);
        // define a custom short action command for the button
        button.setActionCommand("Geeks");
        // add button to frame
        add(button);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        String action = ae.getActionCommand();
        if (action.equals("Geeks")) {
            System.out.println("Button pressed!");
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new Interface();
        //Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI(); 
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you are asking about [Anonymous Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It posts an event to the Swing's Event Dispatch Thread.
The event causes the createAndShowUi() method to be called on the EDT Thread.

Comment: creating an EventDispatchThread and about the correct usage of Initial Thread (Oracle tutorial as part of  Concurency in Swing)